# Inverse of Partioned Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix $A_{(mn)*(mn)}$, which could be partioned into $m*m$ matrices $B_{n*n}$. My goal is to find the inverse of $A$.
Sepcifically, let's say
$B_0=\begin{bmatrix} 
    b_1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & \ddots & 0\\
    0 &  0 & b_n 
    \end{bmatrix}$, a diagonal matrix.
$B_i=B_0+C_i=\begin{bmatrix} 
    b_1+c_i & c_i & c_i \\
    c_i & \ddots & c_i\\
    c_i &  c_i & b_n+c_i 
    \end{bmatrix}$, a symmetric matrix. Then
$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
    B_1 & B_0 & B_0 \\
    B_0 & \ddots & B_0\\
    B_0 &  B_0 & B_m 
    \end{bmatrix}$, still a symmetric matrix.
Now I want to find $A^{-1}$.
I am not very familiar with matrix inverse but I feel like inverse of every matrix $B$ is easy to do. So the question is how can I get $A^{-1}$ from $B^{-1}$'s?
Thank you!

Comment: For most values of $n$ and $m$, $A$ will not be invertible.  Could you therefore provide some context to explain the origin of this problem and how you think inverting $A$ might solve it?

Comment: The basic idea is this matrix $A$ is a precision matrix of a multivariate normal distribution, and I need to invert it to find the estimator of mean and covariance... So I hope it is invertible. Could you let me know why in most cases, A will not be invertible?

Comment: Just try a simple case, such as $n=m=2.$  You will discover the rank cannot exceed $3,$ because (as an easy calculation shows) $(1,-1,-1,1)^\prime$ is in the kernel of $A.$ Generally, if you consider the outer product of $(n-1,-1,\ldots,-1)$ and $(m-1,-1,\ldots,-1)$ as a vector $x$ you can show $Ax=0.$ This isn't the only such vector: the kernel has $(n-1)(m-1)$ dimensions.